# How to delete a selected listbox item from both the listbox and the original list in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox, selecteditem

I'm having problems removing the data in a list which was entered by a user in my textboxes and then stored in a listbox. I know how to remove the selected item in the listbox but when I click my button to show everything in the list, the selected item I just deleted is still in the list.

Here is my code for removing the selected item in the listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VehicleListBox.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    VehicleListBox.Items.Remove(VehicleListBox.SelectedItems[i]);
```

My list is in a class called company and the list is named vehicles. I have looked everywhere for the most part for my answer and cannot seem to find it. I should also mention it's a generic list.

Comment: I'm just using a method in my vehicle class called getDetails which returns the items in a list of strings and then I just use   VehicleListBox.Items.Add(v.getDetails()); to insert the list into my listbox

Comment: getDetails() returns a string of properties from the Vehicle class @GrantWinney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your class design as I understand it, I wrote the following code in a WPF project.  I added a listbox called "listbox1" and a button to the form. I believe the following code does what you want, or at least would guide you to the answer.

```
    public class Company
    {
        public List<Vehicle> Vehicles;
        public Company()
        {
            Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>() { new Vehicle(1), new Vehicle(2), new Vehicle(3) };
        }
    }
    public class Vehicle
    {
        private string _vehicleNum;
        public Vehicle(int num)
        {
            _vehicleNum = "Vehicle" + num.ToString();
        }
        public string getDetails()
        {
            return _vehicleNum;
        }
    }
    Company ACompany = new Company();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach(Vehicle v in ACompany.Vehicles)
            listbox1.Items.Add(v.getDetails());

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listbox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach(Vehicle v in ACompany.Vehicles)
            {
                if (String.Equals(v.getDetails(), listbox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString()))
                {
                    ACompany.Vehicles.Remove(v);
                    break;
                }
            }
            listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItems[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have separate classes, for Company and Vehicle, the Company class is where I make my lists and the Vehicle class is where I have my get/sets and my getDetails method, I also make my lists like: public List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>(); rather than the way you have done it, so i'm not sure if that's an issue but surely it shouldn't matter that my lists are in another class?

Comment: Ah that makes sense! That's why you got a squiggly for SJP's original answer. The problem is that the List.Remove() method only accepts the object type of the List, while SelectedItems[i].ToString() returns the string displayed in the listbox. You'll have to do a check of the removed string against the properties of your vehicle as compared to getDetails(). I have edited my answer to reflect your class design.

Comment: Thank you so much, this code works perfectly, hallelujah! you have been a huge help so thank you! I owe you my soul.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works I tested it.

```
foreach (string thing in listBox1.SelectedItems){
                myList.remove(thing);
            }
```

Comment: that removes the first item in the listbox, but I already have code that removes the item in the listbox, I just need code that removes it from the actual list the item is stored in.

Comment: Every other line seems to be fine, using your code, the middle line says '...has some invalid arguments' I capitalized 'remove' and 'toString()' but now the whole line is underlined @SJP

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you're using `getDetails` to get the list, then one-by-one adding them to the `VehicleListBox`.

An option would be to remove the selected items from the `List` and then update the ListBox accordingly.

You add a simple method to do this:

```
private void UpdateListBox(List<string> vehicles);
```

Replacing `List' with the type you're using.

Alternatively have you tried binding the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox`?

In WPF (for example):

```
<ListBox Name=ExampleListBox, ItemsSource={Binding} />
```

The in code:

```
ExampleListBox.DataContext = myList;
```

This best goes in the Window_Loaded method after you've populated the List.
If necessary then update this when the list changes.

Comment: Where in my code would I put the UpdateListBox method? ..sorry i'm still pretty new to this.

Comment: Not a problem. I've had a bit of a crash course in WPF in the last 6 months so it's all quite fresh. You could add it to the code class of your window. So right-click the wpf window class and select View Code. In here would be ideal.

Comment: And then how would I use that method with my code that I already have?

Comment: Call that method, passing in the update list(with the elements removed, and then re-populate the listbox using `VehicleListBox.Items.Add(v.getDetails());`

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code, you could parse the string back out by reversing whatever `getDetails()` is doing, and then select the appropriate object from your list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < VehicleListBox.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    var item = (string)VehicleListBox.SelectedItems[i];

    VehicleListBox.Items.Remove(item);

    // assuming your company class has only a Name and ID...
    string name = ...  // parse name from item
    int id = ...       // parse id from item

    vehicles.Remove(vehicles.Single(x => x.Name == name && x.ID == id));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to call company.vehicles instead of just 'vehicles'? the lists are in the class Company.